# Creating a simple magazine for school?

Tags: ipad, applications

We are an Apple school with Macs and iPads. I'd like us to start a magazine that's digitally distributed but Newsstand apps would be too complex (plus there's no revenue model) from what I have read on this site. On the other hand, the iPad app [Creative Book Builder](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/creative-book-builder/id451041428?mt=8) is too simple. Using web based applications like [Glossi.com](http://glossi.com/) has limitations in Safari.

Ideally, I'd like to:

- Work on iPads (in an app) OR Macs
- Work collaboratively

Any suggestions? I don't mind if the collaborative element is restricted to that different students send me the different parts, but the compiling and distribution should lead to the magazine being readable on our iPads.
Any suggestions for an app or workflow? Thanks.

Comment: What does work collaboratively mean to your school? People can collaborate around a campfire or morse code telegraph. What is the primary need here?

Comment: Several people working on it at once on their own devices, either physically together or remotely. Like a cloud service - we use Google Docs for example.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that if your okay with the work being done on Macs, the starting point would be to check out Apple's own [iBooks Author](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ibooks-author/id490152466?mt=12) (free, app store). It has a variety of layout choices and distributes through the iBookstore (including at a price of free, if that's what you want). I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "there's no revenue model" but this sounds most promising to me.

[image]

Comment: Yes I'd considered that as we have used it for another project. But it doesn't have the iPad element or the collaboration. However as it similar to pages, people could design separate parts and send them to me to pull together. Or I am now considering using Pages as they are starting to get on board with the cloud element.